# Upload file through Selenium in MacOS (python script)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

Trying to upload an image on chrome using selenium. Particularly on Instagram, without using any available APIs. Stuck on here for a while. Used pyautogui and it works but I need to run it in the background. Can’t seem to find any available solution that works using python. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the relevant code -

[image: code screenshot]

I just use pyautogui to navigate and upload the file. The rest of the code just involves regular logging into instagram, and everything works fine. I am just trying to improve upon the code so I can navigate and pick a file in a more efficient way.

Comment: What you have tried?Post it along with your code.

Comment: I have edited in the relevant code and the description.

Comment: Where is HTML?.

Comment: Please post the actual text of the code. I tried running the picture and my interpreter imploded.